# git show difference between commit messages

Tags: git, git-diff

suppose I have two commits that do exactly the same, but whose messages differ, how can I see this in git?

How to produce this; suppose I am on master, on any commit;

```
git checkout -b test
git commit --amend
// now edit the commit message
git diff master
```

this shows an empty output. The only way I found to see this difference in commit messages is:

```
git show --stat master > m
git show --stat > t
diff m t
```

which produces output like this (I did modify the git log output format a little):

```
1c1
< 65fb678 - (HEAD, test) add bcdef (Fri, 8 Jan 2016 11:23:51 +0100) <Chris Maes>
---
> 7f9c3ee - (master) add bcd (Wed, 6 Jan 2016 11:28:10 +0100) <Chris Maes>
```

is there any **git** command that allows to just see the difference in commit messages (with or without the normal git output)?

**NOTE** my question ressembles [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569699/is-there-a-way-to-compare-two-diffs-or-patches), but I was looking for a **git** command that would allow this.

Comment: A diff between linear commit messages only?

Comment: preferably a solution for multiline message; but just for linear messages only might be a nice start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to compare two diffs or patches?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569699/is-there-a-way-to-compare-two-diffs-or-patches)

Comment: The question ressembles, but my question is more whether there is a **git** command. available. Alternatives are welcome off course

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick for me:

```
diff -w <(git rev-list --max-count=1 --format=%B SHA1) <(git rev-list --max-count=1 --format=%B SHA2)
```

- `-w` ignores whitespace differences.
- The `<( ... )` syntax creates a temporary named pipe which makes the stdout of `git show` commands look and behave like a file, allowing diff to operate on the expected type of input.
- `--format=%B` shows the raw message header+body of a commit message

You could replace `diff -w` with `wdiff` to have a word per word comparison.

**EDIT**

If you really want a `git` command, add this git alias to  `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
        msgdiff = "!bash -c '[ $# = 2 ] && diff -w <(git rev-list --max-count=1 --format=%B \"$1\") <(git rev-list --max-count=1 --format=%B \"$2\")' -"
```

Then you can do

```
git msgdiff SHA1 SHA2
```

Comment: Yes, but you should prefer using `git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 SHAn` (plumbing) to using `git show` (porcelain).

Comment: @ChrisMaes It all depends where you want to use the command. In scripts, you should stick to plumbing command (as much as possible).

Comment: @Amadee : nice answer which does the trick, but I was hoping there was any git command that would allow this; this is patchwork :)

Comment: @Jubobs: my question remains: why is rev-list better? What is the difference with git-show?

Comment: @ChrisMaes `rev-list` is a "plumbing" (i.e. low-level) Git verb, whereas `show` is a "porcelain" (i.e. high-level) Git verb. The output of `git rev-list` is very unlikely to change in future versions of Git; however, the output of `git show` might. Therefore, using `rev-list` makes the approach more robust.

Comment: @Jubobs ok thanks, I didn't know the difference between plumbing and porcelain.

Comment: @ChrisMaes and what goes into porcelain and then plumbing? Git is saying your code is... :)

Comment: @jukobs I edited my answer. As a personal preference I put options that influence the data before options that influence the formatting.

Comment: @Chris Maes no native git command, but you could roll your own.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if you're satisfied with it, and give @Jubobs' comments some upvotes too. :)

Comment: As I said: nice answer that does the trick (whence my upvote), but I am still looking whether there isn't any git command that would allow this...

Comment: There. I just made you a git alias. Tested, works for me. The output of ```git msgdiff``` is identical to that of the answer I gave before.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Git 2.19.0 (~Sep 2018), there's a command for comparing two commit *ranges*: [`git range-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff).

To compare two individual commits referred to by `<rev1>` and `<rev2>`, they need to be expressed in terms of [single-commit ranges](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_other_rev_parent_shorthand_notations) like this:

```
git range-diff <rev1>^! <rev2>^!
```

### Example

```
echo "Some file content" > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m "Add a file" -m "Just an uninteresting file." -m "It has 1 line"
git tag old
git commit --amend --edit
# ... Make some modifications to the commit message ...
git tag new

git range-diff old^! new^!
```

Output:

```
1:  c225627 ! 1:  99b9ca3 Add a file
    @@ Commit message
         
    -    It has 1 line
    +    It has 1 line and 3 words.
     
      ## file.txt (new) ##
     @@
```

### Caveats / Limitations

- The content of the compared commits needs to be sufficiently similar for them to be recognized by `range-diff` as a matching pair, rather than as a complete rewrite *(i.e. removal of one commit + addition of another unrelated commit)*. This should be fine for the scenario described in the question ("two commits that do exactly the same, but whose messages differ").
- Does not work with merge-commits
- This is a porcelain command with output meant for humans. The format is subject to change in the future.
- (rare edge case) The single-commit range syntax `<rev>^!` does not work for parent-less root commits